# EXCEL MAX SUM IF

Tags: vba, excel

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgcoD.jpg)

I am trying to return the values of a column associated with the maximum sum. So if you look at my Excel sheet in the link, there are 19 columns. And column 17 is the max sum as you can see in dark red. Is there a way to return the values of the sum in that column. Like can I return 392, 24, 241, 193, 227, and 461. But I want to have it so all the columns sums are read, and after reading the sum, it finds the max sum. After finding sum, it returns the column values into 6 different excel cells.

```
 MATCH(MAX(Y13:AN13),Table2,0
```

Comment: you can use Match with Max function to find out the column number, then use one index function for each row in that columns

Comment: MATCH(MAX(Y13:AN13),Table2,0  I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Please check the answer, and is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula,

```
=INDEX(Y6:AN12,1,MATCH(MAX(Y13:AN13),Y13:AN13,0))
```

The above formula gives the value in the first row of your table, i.e. 392. If you change 1 to 2, it will give 24 and so on. I think, in your example column 14 has the maximum not the 17th column.